# Target Code Generation using limited available registers

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, code-generation, compiler-optimization

Translate the following code it into machine code and show the
register and address descriptors while the instructions are generated.
(Assume that two registers are available: R0 and R1.)

```
D : = B - C 
E : = A - B 
B : = B + C 
A : = E - D
```

I tried something like this:

```
MOV B,R0
SUB C,R0  
MOV A,R1
SUB B,R1
```

-- R0 contains D
-- R1 contains E

I cannot proceed from here. Since B has no next use in the block (from line number 3), how would the following code turn out?

Comment: Ok, from `D := B-C` you've got `B-C` but where's the `D :=` part?  You're assuming `B & C` are in memory but that `D` lives only in a register?  Why?  Wouldn't it make more sense that A, B, C, D are all the same: having memory locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming some basics about the processor, given your attempt:

You have `D := B - C` almost completed — just store the result into `D` to finish.

```
MOV B,R0
SUB C,R0
MOV R0,D
```

Now all the registers are once again available (though if you happen to need `D` again immediately, a copy is in `R0` — this is hard to take advantage of, though, given the limited registers and other computations to be done).

How do I know that a move to memory is possible?  I don't but based on educated guessing, it would be very odd to have `mov A,R0`, but not `mov R0,A`.